# Getting data in a component after dispatching something in sagas

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm dispatching an action inside the component file to get filtered data from the Api and I want to get that filtered data with useSelector() but it's not working

**Component.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { apiRequestFilteredCourses } from '../../../actions';

const Courses = () => {
  const categories = useSelector(state => state.categories);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  if (categories.isLoading || courses.isLoading) {
    return (<h1>Loading</h1>);
  }
  const query = { category_id: 1 };
  dispatch(apiRequestFilteredCourses(query));
```

**filteredCoursesActions.js**

```
import {
  API_REQUEST_FILTERED_COURSES,
  API_RECEIVE_FILTERED_COURSES,
} from '../constants/actions';

export const apiRequestFilteredCourses = data => (
  {
    type: API_REQUEST_FILTERED_COURSES,
    payload: data,
  }
);
export const apiReceiveFilteredCourses = data => ({ data, type: API_RECEIVE_FILTERED_COURSES });
```

**filteredCoursesSagas.js**

```
import { put, takeEvery } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { apiReceiveFilteredCourses, apiRequestFilteredCourses } from '../actions';
import {
  API_REQUEST_FILTERED_COURSES,
} from '../constants/actions';
import Api from '../services/Api';

// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
function* filterCourses(action) {
  const query = new URLSearchParams(action.payload).toString();
  try {
    const { data, status } = yield Api.get(`courses?${query}`, false);
    if (status === 200) {
      yield put(apiReceiveFilteredCourses(data.data));
    } else {
      console.log(`Action with constant ${API_REQUEST_FILTERED_COURSES} Failed with status code ${status}`);
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('FROM COURSES', e);
  }
}


export default function* filteredCoursesSagas() {
  yield takeEvery(API_REQUEST_FILTERED_COURSES, filterCourses);
  yield put(apiRequestFilteredCourses());
}
```

**filteredCoursesReducer.js**

```
import {
  API_RECEIVE_FILTERED_COURSES, API_REQUEST_FILTERED_COURSES,
} from '../constants/actions';

const defaultState = {
  isLoading: false,
  filteredCourses: [],
  isLoaded: false,
};

const filteredCoursesReducer = (state = defaultState, { type, data }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case API_RECEIVE_FILTERED_COURSES:
      return {
        ...state,
        filteredCourses: data,
        isLoaded: true,
        isLoading: false,
      };

    case API_REQUEST_FILTERED_COURSES:
      return {
        ...state,
        isLoading: true,
        isLoaded: false,
        filteredCourses: [],
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default filteredCoursesReducer;
```

**Api.js**

```
  static async get(url, throwErrors = false) {
    const axiosConf = this.getConf();
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(url, axiosConf);
      if (throwErrors && (response.status <= 100 || response.status >= 400)) {
        throw new Error(`Art API Returned error status ${response.status}`);
      }
      return response;
    } catch (e) {
      Api.showError(e);
      return e;
    }
  }
```

I tried to get the filteredCourses like I did with the categories which is working normally but it completely bugged the app.

```
const filteredCourses = useSelector(state => state.filteredCourses)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your reducer does not seem to be handling `API_REQUEST_FILTERED_COURSES`, so of course, nothing will happen with your state.

Generally, just so you are aware: you are using an **extremely** outdated style of Redux here. Since 2019, we recommend using the official Redux Toolkit, which does not have ACTION_TYPES, switch..case reducers, hand-written action creators or immutable reducer logic with spread anymore. It is only 1/4 of the code. We also do not recommend using Redux-Saga anymore for most use cases - instead, you should be using RTK Query, `createAsyncThunk`, thunks, or the `listenerMiddlware`.
I would highly recommend you to read [Why Redux Toolkit is how to use Redux today](https://redux.js.org/introduction/why-rtk-is-redux-today) and then to take [the official Redux tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts). That old style of Redux you are using here is a pain and there is really no good reason to use that nowadays.

Comment: I will definitely take the redux toolkit tutorial after I finish this dilemma with my code, Thank you so much though,
Can you explain how can I fix my reducer to be able to get the filteredCourses properly?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You will need a new `case` for `API_REQUEST_FILTERED_COURSES` in your reducer file - right now you only have `API_RECEIVE_COURSES` in there which is a completely different string.

Comment: Oh my bad, I provided a different code, I updated it right now can you take a look again at the filteredCoursesReducer.js in my post?

Comment: How did you register `filteredCoursesReducer` in your store config?

Comment: This is the index.js of the reducers folder
`export default combineReducers({
  auth: authReducer,
  categories: categoriesReducer,
  courses: coursesReducer,
  filteredCourses: filteredCoursesReducer,
});`
and the index of sagas
`export default function* rootSaga() {
  return yield all([
    fork(authSagas),
fork(SpecialCoursesSagas),
    fork(episodesSagas),
    fork(categoriesSagas),
    fork(coursesSagas),
    fork(filteredCoursesSagas),
  ]);
}`

Comment: Then you will have to do `useSelector(state => state.filteredCourses.filteredCourses)` to access the `filteredCourses` property managed by that reducer.

Comment: I did this already but that's what bugged my app and keep getting an empty array over and over till it crashes

Comment: Ugh, that was a very good hint that I initially missed: You cannot just `
  dispatch(apiRequestFilteredCourses(query));` in your method body - that will dispatch again at every render!
Do something like `useEffect(() => 
  dispatch(apiRequestFilteredCourses(query)), [query]))` instead.

Comment: Yesss! I figured it out too, thank you so much